Can we use inverse transform sampling in probability loading process of quantum computing?
Recently, I read some papers about Quantum Monte Carlo (QMC), which can speed up the classical Monte Carlo quadratically. However, the efficiency of QMC largely depends on the probability loading process, which encodes the desired probability distribution in the superposition of states.
Since the inverse transform sampling is a common used technique in classical computation, I wonder if we can use it in the probability loading process. As far as I know, there is no such method. So I thought of a way to do it. Here is the method.
Suppose we want to prepare a quantum state to approximately encode a distribution with cumulative function $F$. We can perform the following computation in the quantum computer:
$$|0^n\rangle |0^m\rangle \mapsto \sum_{x\in\{0,1\}^n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^n}} |x\rangle |0^m\rangle \mapsto \sum_{x\in\{0,1\}^n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^n}} |x\rangle |\widehat F_b^{-1}(x)\rangle,$$
where $\widehat F_b^{-1}:\{0,1\}^n \mapsto \{0,1\}^m$ is a proxy of $F^{-1}$ in the sense that
\begin{equation}
     \begin{cases}
        - \frac1{2^{d+1}}<F^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{2^n}\right) - \left(\frac{\widehat F_b^{-1}(x)}{2^d} - M\right)\le \frac1{2^{d+1}}, \quad \forall x= 1, \dots, 2^n-1,\\
        \widehat F_b^{-1}(0) = 0.
     \end{cases}
\end{equation}
Here, the integer pair $(M, d)$ determines the way to interpret the $m$-length binary sequence stored in the second register. Then, we rearrange the final state in terms of a summation about the second register and get
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
        \sum_{x\in\{0,1\}^n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^n}} |x\rangle |\widehat F_b^{-1}(x)\rangle &= \sum_{y\in \{0,1\}^m} \left(\sum_{x: \widehat F_b^{-1}(x) \stackrel{ }{=} y} \frac1{\sqrt{2^n}}|x\rangle \right) |y\rangle\\
&= \sum_{y\in \{0,1\}^m} \sqrt{p_y} |\psi_y\rangle |y\rangle.
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
It was showed in my blog (or this pdf) that $p_y$ is a discrete approximation to density function of the distribution $F$.
I want to ask if there is any unpractical place in the above method, and any comments are welcomed.
